# resize face feature according to the target image size

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-resizing, face

I'm currently working on an eye localize project. In order to train a CNN I have to resize the train coordinates to the appropriate image size. The columns contain 9 face feature points with their x and y component. Those x and y component should be resized as the image gets resized.

```
def resize(target_Width,target_Height):
    df = pd.read_csv('original_data.csv')
    
    for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
        
        if i%1000 == 0: print(i)
 
        row = df.iloc[i,:]
        row_string = row['ImageNameIndex']
        row_data = row.loc[df.columns != 'ImageNameIndex']
        
        if img==None: continue
    
        height = img.height
        width = img.width
        
        y_Column = ['LTY','LBY','RBY','RTY','TLLY','TLRY','BottomY','TRLY','TRRY']
        x_Column = ['LTX','LBX','RBX','RTX','TLLX','TLRX','BottomX','TRLX','TRRX']
        
        for col in y_Column:
            value = df.loc[i,col]
            targetValue = value * (target_Height/height)
            df.loc[i,col] = targetValue
            
        for col in x_Column:
            value = df.loc[i,col]
            targetValue = value * (target_Width/width)
            df.loc[i,col] = targetValue    
            
    to_save = df.loc[:,constants.allColumns]
    to_save.to_csv('all_csv_files/'+ 'resized_train_data.csv')
```

But when I'm trying to plot the face feature on the resized image the face feature aren't correctly.

```
def plotImage():
    
    indexes_to_test = [0,1]
    
    for index in indexes_to_test:
        #get name of Image
        imageName = df.loc[index,'ImageNameIndex']

        #get Image from direcotry
        img = Image.open('./allImages/' + imageName)
        
        #plot Original
        plt.imshow( img , cmap='gray' )
        face_feature_original = original_df.loc[index,constants.columns]
        x,y = getCoordinates(face_feature_original)
        plt.scatter( x , y , c='yellow' )
        plt.title('original')
        plt.show()
        
        #resize Image
        img = img.resize((target_width,target_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        
        #plot resized
        plt.imshow( img , cmap='gray' )
        face_feature_resized = df.loc[index,constants.columns]
        x,y = getCoordinates(face_feature_resized)
        plt.scatter( x , y , c='blue' )
        plt.title('resized')
        plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing how the source data is represented, and how the image is resized. Maybe the origin for the image and the origin for the features are in different locations? I would imagine that would cause issues.

Comment: @Warlax56 Thank you very much. I've just updated the question. Meanwhile, I made some tests: The origin of the resized image and of the original have the same origin

Comment: It's hard to tell but it looks like the points are maybe not getting scaled at all. Confirm that the values are actually getting changed when you save them out and then load them back in, and that you are drawing the right coordinates in your visualization. Also, from the one example it seems like the x and y scales could be getting switched.

Comment: Use [tf.image.resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize) for resizing image. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. Luckily, I have figured it out 3 days ago. I'll post the solution later.